# How to update text with a Countdowntimer in a service

Tags: java, android, android-service, countdowntimer

Let's assume I have a service like that,and I have a TextView to update in every tick,TextView is located in MainActivity. How can I update the TextView in every tick?

```
public class CountDownTimerService extends Service {



                public CountDownTimerService() {
                }



                @Override
                public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                    CountDownTimer.start();
                    return START_STICKY;
                }



                private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimerWithPause(300000, 1) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                        /*

                        In this part i need to update text on MainActivity            
                        */
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                      Log.i("Timer","Timer finished");

                    }



                @Override
                public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                   return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: you dont need a service for such job, place your `CountDownTimer` in your `MainActivity` instead

Comment: No,I need when user closes the app CountDownTimer should work :)

Comment: no, when user closes the app your `MainActivity` is no longer visible so what is a need for "counting down" if there is no `Activity` to show the results?

Comment: When you go back to app it will show remaining time (its a pomodoro timer app :) )

Comment: and? what is the problem with it? just setup your `CountDownTimer` inside `Activity#onCreate`

Comment: When you close the  app CountDownTimer doesnt works (it needs to work on background) , there will be a notification like "Timer is working Remaining Time:12.42 " and when you click that notf it will go main activity and show remaining time (the app Im trying to do is like this  [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=personal.andreabasso.clearfocus)

Comment: i see it now... but you want to show your notification every single second? it will eat your battery in few moments...

Comment: No It will be  one sticky notf when user starts timer and i will update notif in onTick() method   >>>  onTick{ Notf.setContentText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished)}

Comment: Thanks for the warning maybe I can update the notf every min not every second that will be better I think ,like "4 Minutes remaining"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an `IntentService` to pass messages between your `Activity` and your `Service`. You can do it yourself but there is some known libraries which are very efficient and simple to use and do this stuff for you, like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

This is a very helpful tutorial for EventBus, it is very clean and simple to understand, hope it'll help!

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Communicating-with-an-Event-Bus